# SSIS 2012 + Script Component + Custom .dll reference

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, script-component, ssis-2012

Working in SSDT (Visual Studio 2010)

I got code for custom dll in C# (Visual Studio 2010) with Target Framework .net 4.0.
When I refer to above dll in my SSIS Script Component from the location where its been built it throws an error as below though Script Component Target Framework is set to .net 4.0

### TITLE: Package Validation Error

Package Validation Error

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Error at Data Flow Task [Script Component [96]]: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Transformation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=61d0ad25bd7b3c3c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at ScriptMain..ctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.CreateInstance(String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.VSTAComponentScriptingEngine.CreateScriptObjectHelper(Assembly scriptAssembly)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.VSTAComponentScriptingEngine.GetScriptEntryPoint(String versionGuid)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.CreateUserScriptInstance()
Error at Data Flow Task [Script Component [96]]: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Transformation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=61d0ad25bd7b3c3c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at ScriptMain..ctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.CreateInstance(String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.VSTAComponentScriptingEngine.CreateScriptObjectHelper(Assembly scriptAssembly)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.VSTAComponentScriptingEngine.GetScriptEntryPoint(String versionGuid)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.CreateUserScriptInstance()
Error at Data Flow Task [Script Component [96]]: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Transformation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=61d0ad25bd7b3c3c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at ScriptMain..ctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.CreateInstance(String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.VSTAComponentScriptingEngine.CreateScriptObjectHelper(Assembly scriptAssembly)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.VSTAComponentScriptingEngine.GetScriptEntryPoint(String versionGuid)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.CreateUserScriptInstance()
Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: "Script Component" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".

Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.

Error at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.

(Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok figured it out.  Was using wrong gacutil.

Comment: ANswer yourself, and accept the answer, so that people knows the question is answered